# How to fully delete a CouchDB doc on replication

Tags: iphone, couchdb

My app is using TouchDB and is doing a ton of REST requests to pull deleted documents/revisions.  Is it possible to basically tell Couch, "Hey, just delete them, forget about their past"?  I know _changes will show what was deleted, but I'd love it if it just deleted, and didn't ask anything else...  for the sake of iPhone battery life, and 3G connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 'compact' api, which removes all deleted docs from couchDB. You can sometimes launch it.
But standard couchDB replication doesn't send ALL revisions, but only revision history (without data), and last revision. Check your replication algorithm if for compatability with [this](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Posting_Existing_Revisions) API